# What is wrong with this code snippet? Its giving me type declaration error

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-conversion

I am trying to convert this code into VB but it is giving me this error.

CONVERSION ERROR: Code could not be converted. Details:

-- line 1 col 8: invalid TypeDecl

Please check for any errors in the original code and try again.

```
  public Exam GetExamByExamID(int ExamID)
                {
             Exam myExam = new Exam(0,"",0,"","");  
              for(Exam exam1 : ExamArray)
            if(Exam.ExamID==ExamID)
              {
                 myExam.ExamID = exam1.ExamID;
                 myExam.ExamTitle = exam1.ExamTitle;
                     myExam.CreditHours = exam1.CreditHours;
                     myExam.Description = exam1.Description;
                         myExam.PrerequisiteExam = exam1.PrerequisiteExam;

              }
                  return myExam;
```

I changed my code to this but it is still the same error..

```
public Exam GetExamByExamID(int ExamID)
                    {
                 Exam myExam = new Exam(0,"",0,"","");  
                  for(Exam exam1 : ExamArray)
                if(Exam.ExamID==ExamID)
                  {
                     myExam.ExamID = exam1.ExamID;
                     myExam.ExamTitle = exam1.ExamTitle;
                         myExam.CreditHours = exam1.CreditHours;
                         myExam.Description = exam1.Description;
                             myExam.PrerequisiteExam = exam1.PrerequisiteExam;

                  }
                      return myExam;
                       }
```

What exactly do I need to change? Please help.

ok I changed again but same error..it says error in Line 1..

```
public Exam GetExamByExamID(int ExamID)
                    {
                 Exam myExam = new Exam(0,"",0,"","");  
                  for(Exam exam1 : ExamArray)
                if(exam1.ExamID==ExamID)
                  {
                     myExam.ExamID = exam1.ExamID;
                     myExam.ExamTitle = exam1.ExamTitle;
                         myExam.CreditHours = exam1.CreditHours;
                         myExam.Description = exam1.Description;
                             myExam.PrerequisiteExam = exam1.PrerequisiteExam;

                  }
                      return myExam;
                       }
```

Comment: See user1440922 answer below.  Also, you should break your for loop once you find the exam and set myExam.

Comment: Just edit your original code instead of pasting in a new copy that is slightly different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting from the code converter is because you have not included the class **Exam** to be converted so the converter error is saying  "invalid Type Declaration" the first time it encounters the unknown class **Exam**.

this might work for you:

```
 Public Function GetExamByExamID(ExamID As Integer) As Exam
    Dim myExam As New Exam(0, "", 0, "", "")
    For Each exam1 As exam In ExamArray
        If exam1.ExamID = ExamID Then
            With myExam
                .ExamID = exam1.ExamID
                .ExamTitle = exam1.ExamTitle
                .CreditHours = exam1.CreditHours
                .Description = exam1.Description
                .PrerequisiteExam = exam1.PrerequisiteExam
            End With
            Return myExam
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should post the entire class instead of just the snippet. Anyways, I will have the first dig at it.

```
Exam.ExamID and other Exam.*
```

Are you sure they refer to a variable? If you are referring to fields of this class, you should use `this.ExamID` and so on

If not, this is most likely your error.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but try changing

```
public Exam GetExamByExamID(int ExamID)
```

to

```
public Exam GetExamByExamID(int id)
```

along with changing

```
if(exam1.ExamID==ExamID)
```

to

```
if(exam1.ExamID==id)
```